# PHP 5.4.24 timeout due to ob_start()

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to run this set of code

`public function getDataCellContent($row,$data) {
        ob_start();
        $this->renderDataCellContent($row,$data);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }`

When it hits the ob_start() line it just hangs and times out after 30 seconds. I am having this issue on Mac Osx Mavericks. I have an ubuntu server running the same code without this issue happening. Is something messed up with my ini file or is php 5.4.* known to have this issue?

Comment: If you replace `$this->renderDataCellContent($row,$data);` with `echo 'test';` does it still timeout?

Comment: Hmm your onto something it did work fine when I replace that with echo 'test'; So are you saying that the problem is somewhere within that other method?

Comment: Also it put the test out 4 times does that say anything?

Comment: The code within that method is here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#renderDataCellContent-detail should be pretty standard code seeing it's in a framework

Comment: This might be my fault I might be using the wrong version of the framework

Comment: Yeah my fault the framework was the wrong version thanks for the help! Closing this out.